# can volatile variable be serialized in java

Tags: java

Transient and static variable can not Serialize

According to Joshua Bloch’s excellent book “Effective Java Programming Language Guide”, “ the volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field will see the most recently written value "

but what about volatile  be serialized  or not.

Comment: What makes you think `volatile` would cause it not to be serialized?

Answer (score 5):

A `volatile` is typically serialized by Java Object Serialization.  The threading / JMM properties of `volatile` are orthogonal to serialization.

Incidentally, it is *possible* to serialize a `transient` or `static` variable, if you code custom `writeObject` / `readObject` methods to do this.  But, this isn't done by the default serializer.

- You wouldn't expect a `transient` variable to be serialized.  After all `transient` is essentially a *hint* to not include the field in a serialization.
- The reason that `static` variables are not included in an object serializations (by default) is that statics don't "belong" to a specific object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be serialized. The field modifier `volatile` is used for the Java Memory Model to ensure that all Threads see a consistent value. It does not restrict its persistence.